# THREE.SkeletonUtils is undefined

Tags: three.js

When using THREE.SkeletonUtils.clone(object), im seeing that THREE.SkeletonUtils is undefined.
I am refering to this [forum (posted in 2019)](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/loading-a-gltf-model-twice-inside-the-loader-load/8373/2) which suggests using this to clone a 3d model which has skinned animations.

I am importing three.js like this:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.118.3/build/three.module.js';
```

Do i need to reference this SkeletonUtils separately? My understanding is that this is part of Three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of additional modules that are not part of core Three.js, and you need to import them separately. The convention is that if the source file is in the `/examples` folder, then it's not part of the core library and you'll have to import it separately.

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.118.3/build/three.module.js';
import SkeletonUtils from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/utils/SkeletonUtils.js';

// Now you can use it as follows
SkeletonUtils.clone(object);
```

**How do I know if I need to import it separately?**

The best way I've found to differentiate between core classes, and add-on classes is by looking at the documentation. For instance:

- Look at [`Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3), and scroll to the bottom of the page, you'll see `Source: src/math/Vector3.js`.
- Look at [`SkeletonUtils`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/SkeletonUtils), scroll to the bottom of the page, and you'll see `Source: examples/jsm/utils/SkeletonUtils.js`

Since SkeletonUtils is part of the `examples` folder, it needs to be imported separately.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to the official library? Also, why are the external libraries not referenced in the three.js website? How would one know where to look to get the latest libraries?

Comment: Good question. It's not very obvious in the documentation, but I found a trick that works for me, so I edited my answer to include the method I use.